# Minimum requirements for working with local .mdf databases

Tags: sql, .net

I have a simple .net application which uses a .mdf file as the database and LinqToSql technology to access the data.

I run the application on a machine which does not have Microsoft Sql Server installed, and it thorws an exception with the following error:

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52
>   - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database
>   Runtime feature is enabled.) --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file
>   specified

I searched for sql express and came up with microsoft official download site providing a bunch of files

[image]

which of these do I need to install?

And also is it possible to not install sql express and run the application with adding some dlls?

Comment: Which sql server you are using?  SQL server 2008/ 2008 r2?

Comment: I made the database file (.mdf) using visual studio `Service-based database` and it runs on the same machine I develop my application which currently has sql server 2012 but on other machines I get the exception

Comment: You need to install SQL Express 2012 on that machine or other best way you can use .sdf file which is light weight don't need any installation.